# lapply() showed two different results when using with leveneTest()

Tags: r, list, function, lapply

I have this dataframe list containing different dataframes.

```r
df_list <- list(
  `1.3.A` = 
    tibble::tribble(
      ~Person, ~Height, ~Weight,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L

    ),
  `2.2.A` = 
    tibble::tribble(
      ~Person, ~Height, ~Weight,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,
       "Alex",    175L,     75L,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L
    ), 
  `1.1.B` = 
    tibble::tribble(
      ~Person, ~Height, ~Weight,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L
    )
)
```

What I was trying to do was to test for homogeneity of variance among groups (Person in this case). But after several trials of piping lapply() with leveneTest() my codes showed two different results.

This particular code worked and gave me the result I was looking for.

```r
ht <- function(df){ 
  leveneTest(df$Height ~ df$Person)
}

final_ht <- lapply(df_list, ht)
```

However, for this code

```r
wood <- lapply(df_list, function(i) ~leveneTest(y = Height, group = Person, data = i))
```

would give a result showing `<environment: 0x55869b4289b8>`

I have no idea why the function in `wood` didn't return or run the leveneTest.
What is happening  with `lapply()` in both codes?
Can somebody enlighten me on what `lapply()` is doing on both cases?

Also, in the code `ht` it  returns a  warning, is this ok?

```r
In leveneTest.default(y = y, group = group, ...) : 
group coerced to factor. Error in cat("1: In leveneTest.default(y = y, 
group = group, ...) : group coerced to factor.",  : 
  argument 2 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

Would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: Don't use `function(i) ~leveneTest(..)`, you are blending the concepts of base R and `rlang`/`purrr` tilde-functions (they are incompatible). Remove the tilde, just use `function(i) leveneTest(...)`.

Comment: FYI, the `~` returns a formula/expression that stores with it the environment of the calling expression, that's why you're seeing `<environment:...>`.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to R. What does `~` do in base R and in `purrr`? Does that mean I cannot mix base R with other libraries? Or it is not possible to mix  two libraries together?

Comment: You can generally mix libraries, but base R does not use `rlang`'s `~`-function syntax. The closest is R-4.1's new introduction of `\(x) somefunc(x)` to shorten `function(x) somefunc(x)` some, almost entirely for code-golf (fewer characters) purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the tilde, as in

```r
wood <- lapply(df_list, function(i) leveneTest(y = Height, group = Person, data = i))
```

If you were using `purrr` (or some other `rlang`-derived set of functions), then you might use it as something like:

```r
purrr::map(df_list, ~ leveneTest(y = Height, group = Person, data = .x))
# or
purrr::map(df_list, ~ leveneTest(y = Height, group = Person, data = .))
```

In base R, the tilde returns a formula/expression that stores with it the environment of the calling expression, which is why you see `<environment:...>`. In base R, it is often used to define relationships between response and model variables, such as `lm(mpg ~ disp + cyl, data=mtcars)`; it can also be used to define marginal variables, as in `xtabs(~ cyl + vs, data = mtcars)`. In neither of those situations is the actual calling environment (stored with the `~`) used, but it's still there.

In `purrr`, it can be used to more tersely define anonymous functions. The following are, for the most part, equivalent:

```r
lapply(df_list, function(dat) leveneTest(y = Height, group = Person, data = dat))
purrr::map(df_list, function(dat) leveneTest(y = Height, group = Person, data = dat))
purrr::map(df_list, ~ leveneTest(y = Height, group = Person, data = .))
purrr::map(df_list, ~ leveneTest(y = Height, group = Person, data = .x))
# new to R-4.1
lapply(df_list, \(dat) leveneTest(y = Height, group = Person, data = dat))
```